# jQuery, list of unique classes to jQuery set in same order?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to feed jQuery a list of unique classes and have a jQuery set returned with the elements in the same order given. It seems the default is to return in DOM order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in an array of DOM nodes into the jQuery constructor to guarantee the order. Here's one way of doing it:

```
$($.map(array_of_selectors, function(selector) {
    return $.makeArray($(selector));
}));
```

You could replace the call to `$` with `document.getElementsByClassName`, as both results would be converted into an array of elements.

Comment: Good to see other solutions, I like yours. I assume you're turning them into arrays so they're flattened? If so, you could use `$.makeArray()`.

Comment: Why not `$(selector).get(0)` or `$(selector)[0]` actually?

Comment: @zerkms: What if `$(selector)` matches two elements? `$.map` flattens the array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is one way you could do it.

```
var classesInOrder = ["tom", "james", "bob"];

var $elementsInOrder = $("." + classesInOrder.join(", .")).sort(function(a, b) {
    return $.inArray(a.className, classesInOrder) 
         - $.inArray(b.className, classesInOrder);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLjaB/).

This will select them naturally in DOM order, and then sort them, based on the order of your array of class names.

If your elements may contain multiple classes, then you will need to beef up the body of the `sort()` function. Take into account each class.

Comment: @zerkms Refer to last paragraph :)